# Create bar graph without <canvas> in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement this graph with data given below using JavaScript without using `<canvas>`. I got one bar can't see the rest. I want at least 4 bars with x-axis and y-axis numbers (not necessary to be true).

```js
const g = document.getElementById("graph");

const graphData = {
  title: "Wild Animals in Istanbul",
  yAxis: "population",
  data: [{
      name: "pigeon",
      value: 30,
      color: "red"
    },
    {
      name: "wolf",
      value: 20,
      color: "blue"
    }
  ]
}

function createGraphIn(g, graphData) {
  const numOfBars = graphData.data.length;


  var bar = document.createElement("div");
  bar.style.backgroundColor = graphData.data[0].color;
  bar.style.border = "1px solid black";
  bar.style.position = "absolute";
  bar.style.left = "20px";
  bar.style.top = "100px";
  bar.style.width = "30px";
  bar.style.height = graphData.data[0].value + "px";

  g.appendChild(bar);


}
createGraphIn(g, graphData);
```

```css
div#graph {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="graph">

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you only made a bar for one of the graph values. You need to use a loop or something similar to iterate over **all** of them. Here's an example.

```js
const g = document.getElementById("graph");

const graphData = {
  title: "Wild Animals in Istanbul",
  yAxis: "population",
  data: [{
      name: "pigeon",
      value: 30,
      color: "red"
    },
    {
      name: "wolf",
      value: 20,
      color: "blue"
    }
  ]
}

function createGraphIn(g, graphData) {
  var yAxisName = graphData.yAxis;
  var yAxis = document.createElement("div");
  var yAxisContainer = document.createElement("div");
  yAxis.classList.add('y-axis');
  yAxisContainer.classList.add('y-axis-container');
  yAxis.innerText = yAxisName;
  yAxisContainer.appendChild(yAxis);
  g.appendChild(yAxisContainer);
  
  const numOfBars = graphData.data.length;
  var barContainer = document.createElement("div");
  barContainer.classList.add("bar-container");
  for (var i = 0; i < numOfBars; i++) {
    var currentData = graphData.data[i];
    
    var bar = document.createElement("div");
    bar.classList.add('bar');
    bar.style.backgroundColor = currentData.color;
    bar.style.height = currentData.value + "px";
    barContainer.appendChild(bar);
    
    var barDescription = document.createElement("p");
    barDescription.classList.add('desc');
    barDescription.innerText = currentData.name;
    bar.appendChild(barDescription);
  }
  g.appendChild(barContainer); 
}
createGraphIn(g, graphData);
```

```css
div#graph {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}

.bar-container {
/* Responsive sizing. Automatically places bars. */
  display: flex;
  /* Bars flow right to left */
  flex-direction: rtl;
  /* Bars aren't directly up against border */
  padding: 5px;
  /* Puts bars at bottom, not top. To align bars to top, use flex-start instead of flex-end */
  align-items: flex-end;
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  top:0px;
  float: right;
  height:calc(100% - 10px);
  width:calc(100% - 30px);
  margin:0px;
}

.bar {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width:20px;
  width:fit-content;
  padding:0px;
  margin: 5px; // Spaces out bars
}

.desc {
  color:white;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  margin:0px;
  margin-left:2px;
  margin-right:2px;
  text-align:justify;
}

.y-axis {
  transform:rotateZ(-90deg);
  position:absolute;
  bottom:50%;
  left:-23px;
}
.y-axis-container {
  width:20px;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="graph">

</div>
```

Note that I changed some of the styling to eliminate absolute positioning, which could be problematic later on, in favor of responsive `flex`. I also moved most of the styles in JavaScript to CSS.

Comment: thank you very much , but the thing is i want to have a range of numbers in x-axis and y-axis and i wasnt able to do it :/

Comment: That’s doable - just requires a little more JS. I’ll update that to include those when I have time